# Mime type of MS Office documents saved from OpenOffice etc. is not recognized in Debian 9

Tags: debian, microsoft-office, openoffice, mime-types

Just today I faced the problem that document created by OpenOffice package and saved in XLSX format, recognized in Debian 9 as octet-stream instead of valid MS Office format:

```
root@linux# file -b --mime-type /tmp/test.xlsx
application/octet-stream
```

Native MS Office document is recognized without problems:

```
root@linux# file -b --mime-type /tmp/intro.docx
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

Can anyone explain what is wrong with MS Office documents saved from OpenOffice, LibreOffice etc.?
Or maybe something wrong with my Debian settings?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about two different file extensions, and "xlsx" is not "a word processing document," but they *do share the same file format*: they are both zip files with `PK` as the first two bytes.

The easy answer is that `file` is not aware of `.xlsx`, but knows that a `.docx` file is for word. It may be that `file` checks further into the header, as there appears to be some information in the headers pertaining to content type ("content_types.xml"). Excel and Word headers look "identical."

So either `file` is not aware of "xlsx" or OpenOffice fails to put extra metadata in "xlsx" files.

Check the first 64 bytes of the "xlsx" file to see if it looks similar to the "docx" file.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML

Comment: It doesn't matter what extension is taken. Result is the same for two most popular MS Office file formats XLSX, DOCX. By the way, on Gentoo both formats saved from OpenOffice-like processors recognized properly.